# Why is the integral of the tangent function a natural log function?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

I understand the mechanics of using $u$-substitution to solve

$$\int\tan(x)\,dx = -\ln(\cos(x))$$

The textbook/online $u$-sub solution examples smack of "because that's what makes it work."  What I'm looking for is an explanation of *why* it works.  What are the properties of these trig and log functions that enable them to be related via integrals and derivatives?

Comment: You forgot the absolute value $-\ln( |\cos(x) | )$.

Comment: Integrating any function with simple poles will usually end up with $\ln$ showing up.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best way to see it is to go backwards from $-\ln(\cos(x))$ using the chain rule.  We have that $$\frac{d}{dx}\bigl(-\ln(\cos(x))\bigr) = -\frac{d}{dx}\ln(\cos(x)) = -\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} = -\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}= 
 \tan(x).$$  That then means that $$\int\tan(x)\,dx = -\ln(\cos(x)).$$

There's nothing really special about trig functions going on here as much as we have an integral of the form $$\int\frac{-f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx.$$

Comment: Yes this is just the opposite of u-sub.  Still interested in finding if there is a deeper relationship between the trig and log functions, beyond the textbook explanations.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for then in terms of a "deeper relationship." Can you give an example of something you consider "deep"?

Comment: @charlieK3 Well, there's [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), but I'm not sure if that really plays any role here. As mentioned, the `-ln( f(x) )` will show up for any integral fitting that last equation.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that in general:
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx\stackrel{u=f(x)}{=}\int\frac{u'}{u}\frac{du}{u'}=\int\frac{du}{u}=\ln|u|+C=\ln|f(x)|+C$$

---

In your case:
$$\int\tan(x)dx=\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{[-\cos(x)]'}{\cos(x)}dx=-\ln|\cos(x)|+C$$
try making the substitution $u=\cos x$ and see what you get

---

In terms of a deeper meaning, you could use the exponential definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to get:
$$\tan(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$$
and notice that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right]=i\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\ln x$ is a function such that the slope at each $x > 0$ is $1/x$. That is, $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = 1/x$.

By the Chain Rule, $\frac{d}{dx} \ln (f(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.

In your case, put $f(x) = \cos x$.